# Flutter : The named parameter isn't defined Error

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Got the below error while trying to create an Onboarding screen while following a youtube tutorial. Does anyone know how to solve this error and what is the problem?

```
The named parameter 'visualDensity' isn't defined. dart(undefined_name_parameter)
```

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: Instead of attaching a screenshot you should better post the code using triple "```". See how to ask a better question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Okay I will remember this next time Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solved the above error and I'm adding the code snippet just in case someone wants to see the solved code.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHHQJ.png)

Comment: You could kindly edit your answer to include the previous `Pseudocode` as it was with the error then users can compare it with the working code to identify possible error
<pre>
Alternatively, you could explain where the error was so as to assist the rest with a similar issue

Comment: It would be better if you would paste the code here in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to your image you are not placing the {} in the correct place.
Where you have a purple bracket, place a comma and then add visual density property instead of placing it after ThemeData ends.

For your code:

```
theme: const ThemeData(
  scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
  fontFamily: "Schyler",
  textTheme: const TextT heme(......), //Notice only 1 bracket
  visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
) //And now close the ThemeData.
```

Comment: Thanks, brother it worked although I got an error in the theme section I solved that thing thank you.